# How to debug service worker/pwa in ios11.3 mobile device?

Tags: ios, frontend, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My environment:

```
* Safari Technology Preview Release 51 (Safari 11.2, WebKit 13606.1.6)
* iPad with ios11.3 beta6(15e5216a)
* mac os 10.13.3
```

I can debug service worker in mac desktop.

I can debug service worker in Android mobile device.

But I could not found out how to debug service worker in ios11.3 mobile device?

Comment: have you tried emulation on a mac?

Comment: @oninross iphone emulation with ios11.3 ?

Comment: Its worth a try maybe.  Just a suggestion :P

Comment: I just came to ask the same question. Apple apparently *removed* the ability to inspect PWAs on iOS devices from macOS Safari's web inspector. Has anyone confirmed if it is possible to inspect service workers using [Xcode Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html) or perhaps via the web inspector in [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)?

Comment: Anyone figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

After you've connected your iOS device to your computer, open the **Develop** menu in Safari (on your desktop). You should see the remote device listed, under there, you'll see something like the menu below.

[image]

For some reason, the service worker is listed under "Web", clicking that will open Safari's DevTools for the service worker.

If you don't see your device listed, you may need to enable the "Web Inspector", in the iOS settings for Safari.

*I tested this on iOS 14.4, macOS 10.15, and Safari 14.03*

Comment: This is not working for me iOS Safari 14.8.1